# how to let users input their data into different database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using phpmyadmin and what I want to do is create two tables in the database and link those two tables together. For example my first table lets users to register with their usernames and passwords.and the second table lets users to upload their details such as images or some texts. How to link these two tables? How to let database know which users submit what and save those details into correct table?

Comment: For example: in `table1` you will have `ID`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`. In `table2` you will have `USERID` (which will be the same as ID in table1), `AVATAR`, `TEXT` etc. and the columns `table1 ID` and `table2 USERID` will be your link.

Comment: besides that link, do you have some examples for me to refer? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Both tables would require an identifier for that specific user. The users table by convention has this identifier `id` as a PRIMARY KEY, hence it is indexed and is unique (can't be repeated). On the other hand, if you have a table like for instance `user_content`, I would imagine you would want to allow one user to post more than on message, hence it would not be `UNIQUE` though you would want it to be indexed so that you can easily search the content each user has posted.

Here is an example you can use:

table users:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  username varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

table user_content:

```
CREATE TABLE user_content (
  id NOT NULL INDEX,
  messages TEXT
)
```

Let me know if this helped!